# Will an api provider know if the request coming from facebook app or the website?

Tags: facebook

I have a website (lets say a game) and a facebook app (a game on facebook) for it. The website uses a third party api to pull some data based on user input. Will this api provider know if the request is coming from the facebook app or from the website?

Comment: As far as you don't mask your request, it propably will.

Comment: We are talking about an API consumed on the client side then? Games on Facebook run in an iframe, so request origins the API gets to see would still be of your domain, that your app’s content was loaded from. If you use any JavaScript provided by the API owner, they might be able to gather some more info about what “environment” the whole thing is running in though, for example that it is running inside an iframe. (Not on which “parent” page though, the SOP prevents that.)